# Hbase how to count very big column

Tags: hbase

I have a very big column in Hbase, such as: `columnfamilyName:sampleRaw`. the column `sampleRaw` data size could be 20MB or even big 50MB each row. Right now I would like to count how many `sampleRaw` rows in the table. The command `count` is not ok, it can not know if the row has or has not the column `sampleRaw`. The command `scan` is too slow because it tried to print out the column `sampleRaw` while it's very big.

For example, I tried this command:

```
scan 'bigRaw',{COLUMNS=>['rawf':'sample']}
```

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: I didn't write code, I just use scan 'bigRaw',{COLUMNS=>['rawf':'sample']} but the column too big to scan, the screen would crash after a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use java client, you can try KeyOnlyFilter on column base [as you can see here](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/KeyOnlyFilter.html#filterKeyValue(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell)) This way data will not transport to you over network and it will be fast as shell "count" command.